# How do you calculate the absolute value of trigonometric functions?

Tags: trigonometry, absolute-value

How do you calculate:

$|\tan t|= \sqrt{3}$

The answer to this is required to be in the interval $[0,2\pi]$

Comment: Welcome to Math.StackExchange! Here you are expected to show what you have tried. What worked and didn't work when you attempted this problem?

Comment: You better cut the pizza in four pieces because I'm not hungry enough to eat six. - Yogi Berra

Answer (score 2):

$$|\tan(t)|=\sqrt{3} \ \Longrightarrow \ \tan(t)=\pm \sqrt{3}.$$
To solve this, you can look up the values, because they are ones which you will eventually come to remember. We know that if $\tan(t)=\sqrt{3}$ then
$$t=\arctan(\sqrt{3})=\frac{\pi}{3}$$and, similarly,
$$t=\arctan(-\sqrt{3})=-\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{5\pi}{3}.$$